# My Struts 2 first program not working I have follow same Struts 2 tutorial of Javabrain

Tags: struts2, struts

My Struts 2 first code is not working.

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Please provide details as to what isn't working.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

The following [`web.xml`](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/web-xml) for Struts2 filter mapping

```xml
<web-app id="MyStrutsApp" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
 
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
 
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
 
    <!-- ... -->
 
</web-app>
```

Comment: i have problem with 404 resource not found /Projectname